# flex p2p subscriber cannot receive any video stream (using FMS 4.5)

Tags: flash-media-server

I had wrote a p2p system,
which use adobe FMS 4.5 to be the communication server,
and write the AS3 program for publisher(mobile phone) & subscriber(PC).
this architecture works fine in LAN,
but after deploying FMS to the public IP server,
subscriber will not receive any video stream.

any body knows the problem why?
thanks~